# What is the simplest way to add members to a Twitter list using Node.js and Twitter API?

Tags: twitter, oauth, twitter-api-v2

In order to solve a problem related to fetching tweets from 1000+ twitter accounts without hitting the Twitter API rate limits ([What is the most efficient way of frequently getting the last tweets from 1000+ accounts using Twitter API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72672047/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-of-frequently-getting-the-last-tweets-from-1000)) I believe I will have to create a Twitter list. I find it very complicated though and cannot even make it work in Postman even after reading (but not fully comprehending the docs).

I have tested the example here: https://github.com/twitterdev/Twitter-API-v2-sample-code/blob/main/Manage-Lists/Manage-List-Members/add_member.js

but end up with issues related to 'got' package and get down in one rabbit hole after another. In Postman I get authorization errors (401's) even though I have added every authorization code I can find.. The example given above also feels overly complex for, what I expect, is a relatively easy task.

I understand there needs to be further authentication (compared to reading tweets for example) and thus Oauth 1 or 2, since there will be actions (adding/removing) made to Twitter. I can't really figure out exactly what will be needed here though.

My question now is, what would be the simplest possible way (code) of adding members to a list using Node.js and Twitter API? What auth-information is at least needed? As far as I understand: Consumer Key and Consumer Secret.